# Gifs on Sailfish-os

Tags: linux, qml, qt5, gif, sailfish-os

I came here with a little problem, i can't use any local .gif in my code.

I work on Linux with QtCreator and the Sailfish VM to make a Sailfish-os application.

I tried first [this example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-animatedimage.html/), without any success.

```
Rectangle {
    width: animation.width
    height: animation.height

    AnimatedImage { id: animation; source: "../images/animatedimageitem.gif"}
}
```

The execution return :

> QML AnimatedImage: Error Reading Animated Image File file:///bla/bla/.....

Same problem with other permissions on the gif and with an other gif.

After some researches I found [this](https://lists.sailfishos.org/pipermail/devel/2014-September/005048.html) page where someone indicate to download a plugin, but Qt declare (I wish i could put a link but i'm new -_-', see comments) that gifs are already support by default.

The plugin was finally unobtainable and I found this Sailfish/bin/plugins/imageformats/libqgif.so in my directories.

So what can i do to show a gif on this damn thing ?

Comment: Here is the link for default image formats handled by Qt (on the first lines)
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtimageformats-index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well..... I just put it on my phone (Jolla) and the gif works well. So this is the VM who doesn't seems to like gifs ...

Thanks for help though, 
Psycho.

Comment: Using the resources is the correct way. Possibly the gif support plugin is not supported in the VM?

Comment: Maybe, i don't know how i could know that.
And for your information, it works also without the resource file on the phone.
I think i'll still keep your solution.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing is probably related to filepaths. `Gif`s are supported, AFAIK.

Instead of coding the path that way, consider the usage of a [resource file](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/resources.html) to improve portability and platform independence.

- Create a new resource file  (`File -> New File or project -> Qt -> Qt Resource File`)
- The *property editor opens*, click `Add` in the bottom then `Add prefix` and set a prefix such as `/`  (or whatever you like!)
- Click again to select `Add files` and insert your image
- Right-click the newly added image entry and `copy resource path to Clipboard`
- `Build -> Run qmake` (**fundamental** to ensure correct compilation)

The path you copied in the clipboard should be of the form:

```
://PATH_TO_IMAGE.gif
```

Now, given your `QML` code, I can guess the `image` folder is inside source code at the same level as the `QML` folder. Hence, if you added the `.gif` file from that folder you would have the following path in the clipboard:

```
://images/name.gif
```

This can be prepended with the prefix to obtain the final path. If your prefix is set to `/`, as we did above, the final string to be set in the `source` property of your `AnimatedImage` would be:

```
"qrc:///images/name.gif"
```

Obviously, a different prefix or a different path would result in a different final path.

Comment: I tried and it doesn't works for gif.

"QML AnimatedImage: Error Reading Animated Image File qrc:///qml/images/donuts.gif"

But with a png, in the same source folder and resource file "qrc:///qml/images/bla.png",  it's ok.

I forgot to tell that i work with the Sailfish VM, maybe it could help you.

Comment: No you didn't forgot. I just assumed it was simply a path problem. :) Stick with the resource, anyway, that's safer/more portable. As for the problem, does this [link](https://lists.sailfishos.org/pipermail/devel/2014-September/005050.html) help?